# Mapping inherited class with nhibernate hbm

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, subclass, hbm

I Have 2 classes of the same table.

one class, "Entity", contains properties x,y,z from table ENTITY
and the derived class, "ExtendedEntity" contains some more properties (collections - relations to other tables).

I want to map both of them but i couldn't find a way to map subclasses without using discriminator (I dont need one,  sometimes i want to select the Entity object and sometimes the ExtendedEntity).
does anyone has any idea? 
(I tried to map the ExtendedEntity by copying the Entity mapping and adding the new properties, but now when i want to get the Entity object it brings me ExtendedEntity).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the first sentence of your question:

> I Have 2 classes of the same table.

It means that there is only one table *("ENTITY")*. If this is true, there do not have to be, and even should not be any inheritance, if **no discriminator** exists. If both entities will be related to all rows, then (instead of inheritance) we need laziness. And only one `Entity` profiting from the native NHibernate behavior: having lazy properties. And even more, to optimize some queries - the *Projections* could be used.

But again, my suggestion could be correct only if I do understand your scenario correctly: **the two entities were introduced only to reduce workload; but both target all rows in one table**.

The mapping for the only class

```
<class name="Entity" table="ENTITY" lazy="true">
<id name="ID" column="Entityd">
  <generator class="native"></generator>
</id>

<!-- standard default always loaded  properties --> 
<property name="Code" />
<property name="Name" />

<!-- only if accessed, lazily loaded properties --> 
<many-to-one  lazy="proxy" name="Currency" column="CurrencyId" cascade="none" />
<property     lazy="true"  name="Image" column="ImageBinary"  />
...
```

Having this mapping we can get first 5 Entities

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
 .SetMaxResults(5)
 .List<Entity>();
```

And SQL statement generated will be:

```
SELECT TOP 5  this_.EntityId as EntityId3_1_
, this_.Code as Code3_1_
, this_.Name as Name3_1_
FROM ENTITY this_
```

And we can even reduce it with projections

```
var propertyList = NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.ProjectionList();
// projection properties
propertyList.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Property("ID"));
propertyList.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Property("Code"));

var projected = session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
.SetMaxResults(5)
.SetProjection(propertyList)
.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform
                      .AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Entity)))
.List<Entity>();
```

In this case is the SQL Select even smaller. If the `ID` and `Code` would be enough..

```
SELECT TOP 5 this_.Code as y0_
, this_.EntityId as y1_ 
FROM ENTITY this_
```

So, in case I read your question correctly, in your scenario solution would not be in inheritance but in NHibernate native laziness

*NOTE: there could be ExtendedEntity derived from Entity even in this scenario. But not for inheritance via NHibernate mapping but for the Projections Transformation. Some properties from many-to-one properties could be projected this way...*